# android application on a device connect to a php script

Tags: php, android, mysql, webserver

my english is not that good so i will try to explain my problem:

i have a group of .php files in a server (external webserver). i installed the android application on my tablet running android 3.2.1 and i need to:

1) call a php file that do the conection to the db (mysql database)
2) do some stuff on the db (always using the php files that do the work

i have download the tutorial from http://download.androidhive.info/download.php

i have tried in all the ways to make it work for my case but without any result.

maybe i'm just missing something...something really stupid (as always) that is making my connection fail. thansk in advance and i would love some advices (not just for the android java files but also for the php files)

```
<?php

/*
 * All database connection variables
 */

define('DB_USER', ""); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "androidhive"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', ""); // db server
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this out: 
http://ugirusgiarto.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/json-php-mysql-with-asynctask-progressdialog/ 
I think it's better to make the tests on localhost before, with WAMP or XAMPP.
And delete your database connection data before someone get into your database.

Comment: oh sorry. my head is exploding so i didn't see it. im going to read this link you gave me. hoping it will help

Comment: btw...i have already do the test on localhost with wamp and android virtual device an it work...the problem is that i need to connect to external server, and my already-instaled app on the tablet have to do the connection.

Answer (score 0):

place all the files under the same folder and direct your link to that folder (in case its under /var/www simply write the address ommiting that path) then replace the :
require_once **DIR** . '/db_connect.php';
in -  require_once 'db_connect.php';
set files permissions to 777 (just for tutorial, in real life you should grant permissio
that should do the trick...